# Integrable function $f$ such that $\int_I f(x)dx=0$ for intervals of arbitrarily small length.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

A past qual question from my university reads:
Let $f$ be an integrable function satisfying $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=0$. Prove that there are intervals $I$ of arbitrarily small positive length such that
$$\int_I f(x)dx=0$$

I'm not sure how to approach the problem. One has that $\nu(E)=\int_E f(x)dx$ is a signed measure with a Hahn decomposition of $[0,1]=P\cup N$ where $f\geq 0$ on P and $f\leq 0$ on N. But I can't seem to be able to come up with a way of finding an interval with the desired property.

Comment: *Hint*: $x\mapsto\int_0^x f$ is continuous.

Comment: $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is continuous. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, we have that $-\epsilon<\int_x^yf(t)dt<\epsilon$. I was thinking about using Rolle's Theorem because $F(0)=F(1)=0$, and trying to center the interval at the resulting point but $F$ is differentiable only almost everywhere, so I can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: $F$ is continuous, so attains its sup and inf, say $F(c)=\sup F>0$.  If $F$ attains sup on a nontrivial interval then we are done.  Otherwise for every $y<F(c)$, look at the open interval $I_y$ of $F^{-1}((y,\infty))$ containing $c$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that for every $n \ge 2$ there is an interval $I_n$ of length between $1/n$ and $2/n$ s.t. $\int_{I_n} f(x)dx=0$

Fix $n \ge 2$ and consider $a_k=\int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}}f(x)dx, k=0,1..,n-1$; since $\sum a_k=0$ we either have some $a_k =0$ so done or there are consecutive $a_ka_{k+1} <0$ for some  $k \le n-2$; wlog assume $a_k >0, a_{k+1} <0, a_k+a_{k+1} >0$ since if $a_k+a_{k+1}=0$ we are again done, while the other cases are treated as below with the obvious changes.

Then $g(a)=\int_a^{\frac{k+2}{n}}f(x)dx$ is a continuos function for $\frac{k}{n} \le a \le \frac{k+1}{n}$ and $g(\frac{k}{n}) >0, g(\frac{k+1}{n}) <0$ so there is an $a_n, \frac{k}{n} \le a_n \le \frac{k+1}{n}, g(a_n)=0$;

letting $I_n=[a_n,\frac{k+2}{n}]$ we are done since $\int_{I_n} f(x)dx=0, 1/n < |I_n| < 2/n$

Comment: Nice answer. This might simplify the end game: Suppose $a_k<0,a_{k+1}>0.$ Then the function 

$$g(t)= \int_{x_{k-1}+t}^{x_{k}+t} f(x)\,dx$$

is continuous on $[0,1/n].$ We have $g(0)<0,g(1/n)>0.$ By the IVT there is some $t_0\in (0,1/n)$ such that $g(t_0)=0.$ This gives us an interval of length $1/n$ where $f$ integrates to $0.$

Comment: Excellent comment!